# HTTP error 403 when using jsonlite fromJSON in RStudio

Tags: r, api

```
library(jsonlite)
url <- "https://api.nftport.xyz/v0/nfts"
data <- fromJSON(url)
a <- as.data.frame(data)
```

I am new to API, JSON, and R in general. Would like to ask how do I go about building a connection with the API, and retrieving the JSON format, and converting it into a dataframe that I can use.

Have been facing this error.

```
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 403.
```

Comment: HTTP 403 means "forbidden" (ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403). I get the same reply. My guess is that the API requires authentication. If that's the case, then you may need to shift to using `httr` or another package in order to include your API key to access that API.

Comment: According to the [website](https://www.nftport.xyz/), the API key is free. From there, you may be able to use something like `httr::GET(httr::add_headers(Authorization="myapikey"))` (some good references for their API and auth requirements can be found at https://docs.nftport.xyz/docs/nftport/ZG9jOjI4NzY0NTYz-enhanced-ap-is-quickstart, though unfortunately not R-centric).